# Adding a click on event in dynamic table

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, web

Here is my html file code:

```
<body >
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="menu">
         <asp:Label ID="Label2"  runat="server" Text="שלום" 
CssClass="greeting"></asp:Label>
         <asp:Label ID="Label3"  runat="server" Text="אורח" 
CssClass="greeting"></asp:Label>
        <nav id="mainNav">
            <ul>

                <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" 
ImageUrl="~/Images/logo.jpg" CssClass="logo" />

                <li><a href="About.aspx">אודות</a></li>
                <li><a href="Contact.aspx">צור קשר</a></li>
                <li><a href="Registration.aspx">הרשמה</a></li>
                <li><a href="Login.aspx">התחברות</a></li>
                <li><a href="Menu.aspx">דף הבית</a></li>


            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>

    <div class="loginFormBackground" dir="ltr"  style="position: absolute">
        <h1 style="color:deeppink; text-align:center"> קל להכנה</h1>
         <table style="width: 100%; text-align: center;" dir="rtl" 
class="loginDiv" align="center">
             <tr>  
            <td align="center">  
                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="DBDataPlaceHolder" runat="server"> 
</asp:PlaceHolder>  
            </td>  
        </tr>  
    </table>  
    </div>
</form>
</body>
```

and here is my server side code:

```
public partial class Easy : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlDataAdapter da;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    StringBuilder htmlTable = new StringBuilder();
    UserDetails curUser1;
    int count;
    string name = "";

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["recipeID"] = null;
        count = (int)(Session["count"]);
        curUser1 = (UserDetails)(Session["curUser"]);
        if (curUser1 != null)
        {
            Label3.Text = curUser1.firstName + " " + curUser1.lastName;
        }
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            BindData();
    }

    private void BindData()
    {
        string constr; //here is the connection string to database

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblRecipes", con);
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(ds);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

        htmlTable.Append("<table border='1'>");
        //htmlTable.Append("<tr style='background-color:green; color: White;'><th> ID.</th><th>Name</th><th>Address</th><th>Contact No</th></tr>");

        if (!object.Equals(ds.Tables[0], null))
        {
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {

                for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    string idR = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["recipeID"].ToString();
                    string link = "";
                    if (!(DBNull.Value.Equals(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["recipeURL"].ToString())))
                        link = ResolveUrl(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["recipeURL"].ToString());
                    name = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["recipeName"].ToString();
                    string s = ResolveUrl((ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["pic1"]).ToString());
                    string time = "";
                    if (!(DBNull.Value.Equals(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["preparingTime"].ToString())))
                        time = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["preparingTime"].ToString();
                    string kcl = "";
                    if (!(DBNull.Value.Equals(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["kalories"].ToString())))
                        kcl = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["kalories"].ToString();
                    string category = "";
                    if (!(DBNull.Value.Equals(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["category"].ToString())))
                        category = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["category"].ToString();
                    string dificult = "-----";
                    if (!(DBNull.Value.Equals(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["skillLevel"].ToString())))
                        dificult = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["skillLevel"].ToString();
                    if ((s.Contains("easy") || category.Contains("קל")) && ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["show"].ToString().Equals("yes"))
                    {
                        htmlTable.Append("<tr style='color: deeppink; font-weight: bold; text-align: center;'>");
                        //htmlTable.Append("<td clickOn='"+"Function()"+"'>");
                        htmlTable.Append("<td>");
                        //htmlTable.Append(name);

                        if (link.Equals(""))
                        {
                            //htmlTable.Append( ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["recipeAuthor"]);
                            //htmlTable.Append("<a href='" + "ShowRecipe.aspx" + "'>" + name + " </a>");              
                            //Session["recipeID"] = null;
                            //htmlTable.Append("<a href= '" + Function(name)+"'>" + name + "</a>");
                            //Response.Write("<script>alert('yes')</script");
                            //htmlTable.Append("<a href=ShowRecipe.aspx value='"+idR+"'>" + name + "</a>");

                            Button btn = new Button();
                            btn.Text = name;
                            btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
                            htmlTable.Append("<input type='submit' name='name' value='name' runat='server' onclientclick='tn_Click'/>");

                            //htmlTable.Append("<Button text='" + name + "'onClick='"+ btn_Click() +"'/>");


                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Response.Write("<script>alert('no')</script");
                            htmlTable.Append("<a href='" + link + "'>" + name + "</a>");
                        }
                        htmlTable.Append("</br>" + "רמת קושי:  " + dificult);
                        htmlTable.Append("</br>" + "קלוריות:" + kcl);
                        if (!time.Equals(""))
                            htmlTable.Append("</br>" + "זמן הכנה:" + time + "  דקות ");
                        else
                            htmlTable.Append("</br>" + "זמן הכנה:" + time);
                        htmlTable.Append("</td>");
                        htmlTable.Append("<td>" + " מאת  " + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["recipeAuthor"] + "</td>");
                        htmlTable.Append("<td>");
                        htmlTable.Append("<img src='" + s + "'visible='true' runat='server' style='width:300px; height:200px;'/>");
                        htmlTable.Append("</td>");
                        htmlTable.Append("</tr>");
                    }
                }
                htmlTable.Append("</table>");
                DBDataPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = htmlTable.ToString() });
            }
            else
            {
                htmlTable.Append("<tr>");
                htmlTable.Append("<td align='center' colspan='4'>There is no Record.</td>");
                htmlTable.Append("</tr>");
            }
        }



    }

    private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }
```

I have tried to create dynamic buttons inside all recipes which dont have link(url to other website). In this case i must create a link to other web form with the specific recipe to show its details. I got lost a bit with a syntax of html code inside the server side. When im trying onclick event it doesnt work. Im probably sure that im not doing this in the right way. Please help.

Comment: Why not use a GridVIew instead of creating your own table as a string? And you cannot add `runat='server'` to a string and expect the input to behave like an actual Control. It does not work that way.

Comment: you have created btn object as button control with "btn_Click" handler, but you are not adding it in your dynamic table, you are just adding button with clientclick function only which triggers client side click functionality...

Comment: How can i add btn object to a dynamic table?

Comment: Try create using asp.net table control and add button obj in that table, this link will help you, https://forums.asp.net/t/1763154.aspx?Adding+Buttons+to+a+Table+with+method